# what is“Connect”: function () mean in this code snippet

Tags: javascript, function

This post is regarding code snippet taken from 
Professional xmpp programming with javascript and jquery.
In this piece of code what does "connect" : function mean.
Is it a function with name connect

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(‘#login_dialog’).dialog({
autoOpen: true,
draggable: false,
modal: true,
buttons: {
“Connect”: function () {
$(document).trigger(‘connect’, {
jid: $(‘#jid’).val(),
password: $(‘#password’).val()
});
$(‘#password’).val(‘’);
$(this).dialog(‘close’);
}
}
})
```

Comment: Your current code results in a `SyntaxError`. So-called smart quotes rarely work in programming. If you fix that, it looks like `Connect` is just a property name in the `buttons` object

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you please explain it more

Comment: Just type in the code into any editor and try to run it - you'll see that it results in a `SyntaxError`. You should fix that first.

Comment: https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/tree/master/ch03

Comment: @CertainPerformance the full code is here

Comment: The code there is not using smart quotes. When you post a question, you should make sure that the code you post *exactly represents* the code you're concerned about, and doesn't have syntax errors

Comment: @CetainPerformance you have to comment this two lines there and have a jabber server installed and script folder should also be included
  <script src='../scripts/flXHR.js'></script>
<script src='../scripts/strophe.flxhr.js'></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case Connect is part of the map that represents the buttons of a dialog in a jquery plugin.
Without any further information it should be the label of the button and the function assigned to it is called when one clicks on this button.

In your case the plugin used is Jquery Ui.
You can read more about it here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: can please tell me how can we know that connect gets called when button is called.please explain to me what is happening behind the scene

Comment: In order to explain mor we would have to know what plugin is used here.
In short a dialog is probably created an the function is assigned to the onclick of the generated button.

Comment: @NeilsNet it depends on strophe.js jqueryui and jquery

You can see the code here https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/tree/master/ch03

Comment: Actually it uses the dialog from jquery ui. I added a link to its documentation to my response

Comment: you are super.i like for you answer from my side...:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Connect is being assigned an anonymous function reference.

Comment: Wrange can you tell me what is anonymous function reference